# Any way to kill an application on high temperature?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, temperature, cpu

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 and I'm thinking of running a process 7/24, but it sometimes uses CPU too much, and from my last 2 questions, I understood that Raspberry Pi 3 cannot power itself off on high temperature. Because of this, I decided to configure raspberry pi to kill that application on high temperature, but I don't have any ideas about how I can do that. How can I do that?

Comment: other option/only a suggestion: with Munin ( http://guide.munin-monitoring.org/en/latest/tutorial/alert.html ) you can monitor i.e. cpu temperature and get an alert (i.e. by email) if it exceeds a defined temperature (and much more)

Answer (score 5):

The following shell script uses the videocore utility `vcgencmd measure_temp` to get a line like `temp=37.4'C`. It then does some string magic to isolate the `37` from that string, which is then compared to 35. If it's smaller, it waits a second, then tests the temperature again. If it's 35 or more, $HOT_PID is killed. That PID was set to the program in question, which was started in the background.

```
#!/bin/sh
/path/to/hot/app &
HOT_PID=$!
while [ $(vcgencmd measure_temp|{ IFS== read DUMMY TEMP ; echo $TEMP ; }|{ IFS=. read INTTEMP DUMMY ; echo $INTTEMP ; }) -lt 35 ] ; do sleep 1 ; done
kill $HOT_PID
```

Note this fails on applications which fork, because you had to kill all the child processes, too. But you could still use the test line as a base and make a better script. Or simply `shutdown now` the Pi.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can't test it now but I'll comment when I test it. Also, isn't 35 too low?

Comment: Please adjust it as you need it.

Comment: instead of `kill` it could be useful to suspend process execution with SIGSTOP signal for later resumption